# MySQL - Grant user permission to create table as long is it has a prefix in the name

Tags: mysql, permissions

I'd like to grant a user permission to create tables in a database so long as the table has a particular prefix, let's say `example_`.

I've tried the following:

`` $ mysql -u root -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE example;
mysql> CREATE USER xyz@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT CREATE ON example.`example_*` to xyz@localhost; ``

However, when I log in to `example` as `xyz` I'm unable to create tables:

`$ mysql -p -u xyz example
mysql> CREATE TABLE example_table (id INT);
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE command denied to user 'xyz'@'localhost' for table 'example_table'`

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a wildcard facility of that sort.

Don't prefix columns with the table name.    If you need qualification, do `tablename`.`columnname`.

Don't prefix tables with the table name.  If you need qualification, do `dbname`.`tablename`.

If necessary, move all the examples into a separate db and `GRANT` suitable permissions to suitable users for that database.